# What is safe way to communicate java applet -> MySQL

Tags: java, php, mysql, authentication

Im making a small java game which is running on webpages. Now Im trying to get my game to communicate with MySQL db and its now doing it via PHP.

So here is what happens:

1. There is basic login system which sets session when logged in (PHP).
2. When the java game is asking data from db it sends POST (URLConnection) to PHP page.
3. PHP page checks that session is set, if so it echos wanted info from db.
4. Java game plays with PHP page output.

Working and running like a dream!

Only thing Im worried is that I actually have to change and store more data into db via this same cycle. So if you have your session running you can basicly do nice HTML form and set better weapon for your character.

I tried to google basic ways to communicate with databases and the basic theory how servers work safely. No easy answers.

So shortly my question is,

What is the safe and right way to communicate (read and write) between java app and database?

And for future do the same with android apps etc. Im glad if you just give me a kick to right direction.

Thanking you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. If there is *any* way a client can issue arbitrary SQL queries directly to the server from the outside, then there's virtually no protection that prevents anyone from doing anything with the database they want, include `SELECT * FROM users` and `DROP TABLE users`.

You always want an *API* between the outside world and your server components which defines clearly allowed actions and blocks anything else. Allowing arbitrary SQL queries is basically an API allowing unrestricted access to everything in the database, which is usually too broad.

The way you usually do this is to define a number of *actions* that a client can do and expose them via an API, say a REST API. The Java client talks to this API, whatever happens behind the scenes on the server is irrelevant. It's not about "talking to a database", it's about *doing certain things on the server*. And the number of those things is and should be limited.

Comment: Now Im making limits by taking attributes like setWeapon=3 and then making SQL query "UPDATE users SET weapon=setWeapon WHERE userId = [userIdFromSession]". How can I do these kind of "updates" safely even trough API? Sorry if Im going out of context, just trying to get the picture. ;)

Comment: Because your API defines a limited number of queries that can be executed and you're just interpolating the values sent by the client (hopefully in a way that prevents SQL injection). And your API is checking whether the user is allowed to do a certain action or not (right?!). That's safe. Allowing anyone to execute any SQL query is not.

Comment: Yep, but how can I prevent user to log in and then use my API via HTML <form> and set a weapon of his/her choice? Im not so afraid of injections than cheating in the game.

Comment: That's a rather different topic and goes into the realm of **your server is checking whether a user is allowed to do something or not**. This requires that the server knows enough about the game state to decide what is currently allowed and what is not. This is a pretty complex topic in any server-client application, but especially in games which run mostly exclusively on the client. There's no easy answer and I don't have one.

Comment: OK. I'll keep on searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this articles...

[**What Applets Can and Cannot Do**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

[**Security Issues with the Applet**](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/applet/security-issues-with-the-applet.shtml)